# WordPress without jQuery - Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Relatively new to WordPress development. I am creating a new custom theme from scratch and would really like to just write vanilla javaScript without slowing things down with all the bloat of jQuery. I was thinking I could just simply dequeue jQuery.

Would this break anything behind the scenes for WordPress to function or is there no dependency?

Comment: have you checked out at WP forum or their docs?

Comment: Is it for front-end, or back end?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I am only looking to use some JS on the front end.

Comment: @Jai No. Good point. I just did a Google search and a search on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is unlikely to slow you down as it's simply a bunch of optimized DOM selectors/DOM methods/utility functions.

You should be able to proceed with Vanilla JS unless any plugin or library you are using depend on it.

Comment: Just trying to reduce download time of my site and keep it nice and quick from the early stages. Not including jQuery should reduce download time I reckon?

Comment: Yes, that statement is true. For first time users, it will reduce download time. For return visitors, it should be cached by browsers. Also checkout jQuery-like alternatives like http://zeptojs.com/ which is more light-weight

Comment: Minified, jQuery is like 85kb. It's not going to slow your site down, especially if you serve it from a cdn host (like Google Hosted Libraries). But yes, of course you can dequeue and not use jQuery, with one caveat: you must use a theme or develop your own that doesn't rely on jQuery.

Comment: There is more and more talk about how [JavaScript is more expensive for the browser to process than the equivalently sized image or Web Font](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/javascript-startup-optimization/). So it's not just _like 85kb_, an this is especially true for mobile devices with weak cpus.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the WP-JSON API plugin (comes with WP since 3.7 i think) and build your WP-site as a SPA using React/Vue/Angular/Whatever.

If you choose to go that route you wont have any bloat caused by anything but yourself. Always test your code. I personally like Vue.js, proper open-source framework, works like a charm for WP-development

Check this link out: https://snipcart.com/blog/reactjs-wordpress-rest-api-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory jQuery will add to the download, but *not as much as you think*.  jQuery gets loaded once if you set cache properly, all following pageloadfs, jQuery gets laoded from cache. If you use a [CDN like Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery), big chances that your visitor already has it cached because they loaded it on another page. The parts of jQuery which you don't use, don't activate, they're smart like that.

Also, jQuery fixes some cross browser behaviour which you don't need to worry about and it offers a lot of functionality makes things a whole lot simpler, allowing you to focus on more interesting stuff.

TL;DR: **jQuery will save you a much time building code, with(imo) a very minor cost**. I do recommend using native JS when relevant, e.g. when you want a href of a clicked anchor: `this.href`.